# Populate an Array in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program for class that needs to ask the user for 3 different test scores from 3 different people and store that in an array. I am having issues with populating the array from the user input.

It should ask the user to enter in 3 scores for person 1, person 2, and person 3. Then Store it in a "three-element array of structure variables; each element will contain the test scores for one student"(to quote exactly what the book said).

Everything else I can do so any suggestions on how to tackle this would help me greatly.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?  What have you tried so far, and what didn't work?

Comment: The problem is how to start it in general. How do I store user entered data In a 3 element array. I don't know if its just a bad day for my brain or what but i cannot for the life of me think of how to start that off. 
        strInputScore1 = InputBox("Score 1:", "Test Scores")
        strInputScore2 = InputBox("Score 2:", "Test Scores")
        strInputScore3 = InputBox("Score 3:", "Test Scores")
Is the Input or something Like it but from there I do not know what to do.

Comment: Try using [Array Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorials on Array

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_arrays.htm

Creating an Array

```
Dim scores(2) As Double   'this creates an array with 3 elements
```

Populating it

```
scores.SetValue(99.5, 0) 'SetValue(the score fetched from input box, index number)
```

...and so on

Good luck.